# Generic type <P> converted to paragraph tag in Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, javadoc, checkstyle

I have a Java class with a generic type P. I want to document it in Javadoc. Normally I just do this:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param <P> the type of publisher
 */
```

This shows up fine in actual Javadoc. However, CheckStyle is warning me that I need to document the type P because it renders <P> as a HTML paragraph. Also, the Eclipse formatter interprets it as a paragraph as well, so it messes up the formatting.

Is there a better way of documenting type parameters with type P? I know I can disable the Eclipse formatter to no longer auto format javadoc, but I'd rather not (and it wouldn't solve the checkstyle problem anyway).

I also know I can just rename P to something else, but given the number of generic types I am working with here, it would make things a lot less readable.

Comment: Best Java generics question in a long time.

Comment: How about using another letter for the type parameter? Using `P` for publisher is nice to have, but wouldn't `T` work as well?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker please read the last paragraph of my question :)

Comment: what happens if you escape the P with &#80;   ?

Comment: Does using &lt; for < and &gt; for >  works with CheckStyle?

Comment: @MrT Just tried it, checkstyle still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @user158037 unfortunately no :(

Comment: You could also use "PUBLISHER" instead of "P" although publisher might be interpreted as constant.

Comment: @PieterDeBie that could be a good workaround. But I wanna know if there is a real solution

Comment: Can you try {@literal <P>} instead of <P>

Comment: @HRgiger tried it, but then it doesn't show up in Javadoc anymore (and Checkstyle still disagrees)

Comment: I see seems like best way to do this refactor eclipse and checkstyle plugins:)

Comment: What is your Checkstyle version? They've recently redesigned their Javadoc parser.

Comment: @Thomas I'm running version 6.8.0.201507251301 of the Eclipse plugin for Checkstyle. I'm not sure which Checkstyle version it corresponds to, but Eclipse tells me the plugin is up to date.

Comment: That's Checkstyle 6.8.1. I would expect current versions to have this problem, rather than older ones. But I see the question is already resolved for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FOR POSTERITY: Turns out Checkstyle handles it just fine. The problem is that the whitespace added by the Eclipse formatter made Checkstyle (reasonably) argue that the Javadoc was incorrect. I also found an existing bug report for this bug in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=121728

Answer (score 6):

This is a **bug** in CheckStyle.

The [official Javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#param) says that notation is correct:

> Example of a type parameter of a class:
>
> ```
>  /**
>   * @param <E> Type of element stored in a list
>   */
> ```

If you're stuck with this version of CheckStyle, then the only way to satisfy both constraints is to rename your `P` type parameter to something else.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I will have to use a workaround in the end, but at least now I have reassurance that there is (currently) no better way.

Comment: Turns out I've been falsely blaming Checkstyle. You couldn't know because I didn't ask the question properly. See my own answer for details. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just skip "<" and ">" characters. They are not part of the type name; they are part of syntax.

```
@param P the type of publisher
```

(Not sure how it works with CheckStyle, but Eclipse should be satisfied.)

Comment: Unfortunately, Checkstyle is not. For me, this is a requirement

Answer (score 1):

We found out that hitting Ctrl+S to save and then Ctrl-Z to undo the formatting will correctly save the Javadoc with an `@param <P>` tag.